# how does google+ performs its requests?

Tags: ajax, google-plus

I noticed that google+ instantly updates when someone shares something with me. For curiosity i went to chrome's "inspect element" and watched the ajax requests. Surprisingly, there was no requests! How does google+ updates his content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technique has a number of names, of which [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is the most common I've seen.

Comment: They don't use either of them

Comment: @genesis Care to enlighten us beyond a "nuh uh!"?

Comment: huh..? What are you talking about ?

Comment: You say "they don't use either of them". What are they using if it's not Comet?

Comment: wow! that's a very interesting technique! +1 even if it's not the right answer (: